# Выпадающее меню

Tags: jquery, menu, плагин

Может, кто-то знает плагин на jquery (чтобы была плавность переходов, задержка и т.п.) для реализации такого вот [меню](http://doctorhead.ru/).

Comment: Плагин? В действительности верстка такого меню выглядит сложнее, чем есть на самом деле.

Comment: Плавность переходов, задержка и тому подобное... потому и плагин.

Comment: Что-то я не увидел там ни плавности, ни задержки. Может не туда смотрю?

Comment: Добавил, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Но, даже несмотря ваши требования, все это реализовать не так сложно, как кажется. Попробуйте. Или ждите, может, кто-то что-то подскажет.

Comment: Я понимаю, что несложно, но уже 100% есть готовое решение, и написано намного качественней, чем напишу это я...